# URL Routing to single Index File

Tags: php, url, routes

I have a website: http://chanl.co.uk/ that is effectively a blog. Each post has it's own permalink that goes to a specific URL on the page. In projects i've worked on in the past, these links would be routed to different index files in seperate folders that would use the same template for each  post and would then select the data dependent on it's permalink. Im looking for a way to have a single file that all posts will route to when they are accessed. Almost just link how Wordpress would use a "single-post" template for every post that is on a website.

I'm a little stumped as how to go about this form of dynamic routing almost, and don't know where to start. Would a route have to be auto-generated for every post in the database or is there some more practical way to solve the issue.

Awful Diagram:

```
(My train of thought) 

Chanl - Post1 / Index.php
        Post2 / Index.php

(Optimal Solution)

Chanl - posts.php (all posts are directed here)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look at how a simple php framework works, basically every request is passed to an **index.php** file in your root directory and then routes are defined by your URLs using (guess what!) a router...

Some things you will encounter are.

1 - the front controller patter
2 - the MVC pattern
3 - Controllers and Methods (which are also known as functions)

So basically your typical URL route would look like this

www.example.com/shop/product/id=12

This translate to

www.example.com/controller/method/parameter

Your controller is a php **class**, the action is a function in that class and the parameter is any data you want to pass in (for example an id).

All frameworks need routing and routing solutions range from relatively simple to very complex.

I recommend this video to learn how a basic famework functions and then move on to a real framework such as laravel. It takes some head banging (for me a couple of weeks of pain) but it will eventually click.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OsCTzGASImQ&list=PLfdtiltiRHWGXVHXX09fxXDi-DqInchFD